# Largest eigenvalue of a block diagonal matrix is an eigenvalue of the largest block?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider this square matrix $C =  \begin{bmatrix}
A& 0   \\ 0  &B
\end{bmatrix}$, where $A$ and $B$ are also square matrices. Suppose $A$ is larger in the sense that is an $n \times n$ matrix, while $B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix, and $n > m$. Also suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices.

I know that the set of eigenvalues of $C$ is equal to the multi-set of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

**Question**: Suppose the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct from the eigenvalues of $B$. Must the largest eigenvalue of $C$ be an eigenvalue of $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Take, for example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1},\quad
B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&2} 
$$

Comment: Duh. I should have realized this. Thanks! +1 and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $E(T)$ the set of eigenvalues of any matrix $T$. I don't know what you mean by *multi-set*, but the set of eigenvalues of $C$ is given by $E(C)=E(A)\cup E(B)$. The largest eigenvalue is just the largest element in this union. It can be either in $E(A)$ or $E(B)$. It's very easy to find examples where this eigenvalue is *not* an eigenvalue of $A$. Just take any $A,B$ you like, such that $\max(E(B))>\max(E(A))$.

Comment: "multi-set" means that you can repeat non-distinct elements, so that elements can have "multiplicities" within a multi-set.  So, for example, $\{1,1,2\} \neq \{1,2\}$ for multi-sets.